Sync UITableView scroll with keyboard appearance
I have a tableView with four cells. Each cell has a UITextView with a long-long text. When user starts to edit text, keyboard appears and the tableView scrolls up. I would like it to happen simultaneously with the keyboard appearance (like in Apple Notes app). However there seems to be a slight delay.
How it happens:

How I would like it to happen:

Here is my code:
private func addKeyboardObservers() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc
private func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    guard let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
}

@objc
private func keyboardWillHide() {
    tableView.contentInset = .zero
}

PS: Originally I tried to achieve this very behaviour using SwiftUI, but there scrolling seemed even more messy. If someone can suggest a SwiftUI solution, would be much appreciated. Peace ✌️

This is not what you asked, but as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue is really old-style code. We haven't needed to talk like that in over a decade. Basically you are talking Objective-C in Swift. Instead, talk Swift.

As my experience, you should wrap your code which update UITableView content insets in an UIView.animate block. Here, the magic number 0.25 is amount of time for keyboard to fully show on screen.
private func addKeyboardObservers() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc
private func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    guard let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
    })
    
}

@objc
private func keyboardWillHide() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.tableView.contentInset = .zero
    })
}

